# Website login using google apps script and extract data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, login-script

I am trying to learn some google apps script, so decided to do something like:

- login to a website (say my own stackoverflow).
- check my reputation value and collect the achievements by date.
- store the achievements in tabular format with following columns: date, achievement, score or badge based on that achievement.

```
function stackLogin() {
  var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
  var payload = {
    "Email":"stackoverflow login",
    "Password":"login password"
  };

  var opt = {
    "payload":payload,
    "method":"post",
    "followRedirects": false
  };  

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);
  //var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(encodeURI(url), opt);

  var sessionDetails = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];

  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode()); 
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  //Logger.log(sessionDetails)

  // write the response (which is a fetched HTML from stackoverflow) to a file

}
```

**I receive the following log after running it:**

```
[19-03-10 19:39:53:620 PDT] 200.0
[19-03-10 19:39:53:622 PDT] <!DOCTYPE html>


    <html class="html__responsive">

    <head>

        <title>Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">

....
....
continue ....
```

So, does the "response code = 200" mean I was able to login?

How do I run further analyses to extract the reputation values and achievements?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand what you want to do, if your goal is to retrieve your information from Stackoverflow, how about using [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)?

Comment: @Tanaike: Using API is one way of doing it. Currently I am trying to learn so I want to try it both way. This method is more like web scrapping, but I want to login into my account to extract those values. After I have learned how to do it this way, I plan on using API method.

Comment: @Tanaike: I just want to login into the stackoverflow site (using my account) and extract the data from "acheivements". That's all.

Comment: That's a task that is doable in almost any http-capable language. If you don't know how to do the *task itself*, trying to learn both the task minutiae and the rules of a new environment / language is not really recommended. For example, have you done any research at all about how one authenticates with a website? What about with Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange in particular? Have you inspected the login process as performed in a browser? And so on.

Comment: @everestial007 Thank you for replying. I could understand about your question.

Comment: 200 would just mean you were able to successfully load the page.

Comment: Thanks for response. If I put login url I get response code 302. So, does that mean I was able to login? Cant get 303. @tehhowch I have learned some some web scraping (mostly on wikipedia data) using python. I can understand html parsing. But, here I first want to verify if I am able to login. Then next step that involves clickable like web scraping.